# delegate return nil after calling it in a class

Tags: swift, delegates, location-services

I'm using this class to get the location and send it with a delegate to another view controller, but the delegate is returning nil when called.
my class:

```
protocol LocationUpdateProtocol {
    func locationDidUpdateToLocation(location : CLLocation)
}
/// Notification on update of location. UserInfo contains CLLocation for key "location"
let kLocationDidChangeNotification = "LocationDidChangeNotification"
class LocationServiceHelper:NSObject,CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    static let sharedManager = LocationServiceHelper()
    private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var currentLocation:CLLocation?
    weak var delegate :LocationUpdateProtocol?
    private override init() {
        super.init()
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    // MARK: CLLocationManagerDelegate

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let delegate = self.delegate else {
            return
        }
        currentLocation = locations.first
        let userInfo:NSDictionary = ["location":currentLocation!]
        delegate.locationDidUpdateToLocation(location: currentLocation!)
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: kLocationDidChangeNotification), object: self, userInfo: userInfo as? [AnyHashable : Any])
    }
}
```

I called the delegate in another class below:

```
var locationServiceReference = LocationServiceHelper.sharedManager
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        fillFields()
      locationServiceReference.delegate = self
        self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true
    }

func locationDidUpdateToLocation(location: CLLocation) {
       // print(location)
        // let myLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)
        let myLocationForTesting = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 33.410165, longitude: 35.480060)
        myLocation = location
            let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: myLocationForTesting, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))
        self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    }
```

in the did update location , the delegate is returning nil, any idea what's happening? the function isn't been called, since the delegate is returning nil.

Comment: Where have you added `LocationUpdateProtocol`? Add that code too.

Comment: its in this class, at the top

Comment: I meant where you want to `LocationUpdateProtocol delegate` must be called? Like where you initialized `LocationServiceHelper` ?

Comment: done, question updated

Comment: Check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure that your controller still in memory
2. You don't need to use guard. Optional chaining works better in such cases:

```swift
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    currentLocation = locations.first
    let userInfo:NSDictionary = ["location":currentLocation!]
    delegate?.locationDidUpdateToLocation(location: currentLocation!)
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: kLocationDidChangeNotification), object: self, userInfo: userInfo as? [AnyHashable : Any])
}
```

3. Make sure that `func locationManager(_:didUpdateLocations)` called after delegate setted.
4. For future you want to pass last location when delegate changes as:

```swift
weak var delegate :LocationUpdateProtocol? {
    didSet { 
        guard let last = currentLocation else { return }
        delegate?.locationDidUpdateToLocation(location: last)
    }
}
```

5. Since it's singleton with only 1 delegate, make sure that you not setting delegate to `nil` or another short living obejct somewhere else

Comment: didn't work, delegate is still returning nil, its not crashing, but the function isn't been called because the delegate is still nil

Comment: I'm getting an error: weak must not applied to non-class-bound LocationUpdateProtocol , consider adding a protocol conformance that has a class bound

Comment: @MrJ change protocol declaration to `protocol LocationUpdateProtocol: AnyObject {`

Comment: So do that. `protocol LocationUpdateProtocol : class`

Comment: @matt `class` will be deprecated in favor of `AnyObject`. So better start using it now :) https://forums.swift.org/t/class-only-protocols-class-vs-anyobject/11507/4

Comment: @MrJ add `weak var delegate :LocationUpdateProtocol? { didSet { print("Delegate: \(delegate)") } }` and check logs what happening

Comment: its not entering in the didSet function

Comment: @MrJ then only one possible reason: you not setting delegate.

Comment: @ManWithBear I had no idea! Thanks (Hahaha, and the discussion at your link quotes me!)

Comment: I'm calling It from the second view as u have suggested above

Answer (score 0):

**This code -**

```
var locationServiceReference = LocationServiceHelper.sharedManager
```

executed before your `delegate` set, that's why `delegate` return `nil` always.

**Replace**

```
var locationServiceReference = LocationServiceHelper.sharedManager
```

**With**

```
var locationServiceReference : LocationServiceHelper!
```

And initialize after `viewDidLoad()` get called.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    locationServiceReference = LocationServiceHelper.sharedManager
    locationServiceReference.delegate = self

}
```

Hope it will hep you. Let me know if still you are having any issue.

Comment: the problem is in the first class, where the protocol exist, the since the delegate is staying nil, so the function will not be called, I tried your solution but didn't work

Comment: `locationServiceReference.delegate = self` line will set the `delegate` in the class. Otherwise `delegate` remain `nil` always

Comment: did you made changes as i suggested